# Why are some of my Secondary IPs missing after a YUM update on Amazon Liunx 2

Tags: amazon-ec2, udev, amazon-linux-2

On Sunday, I did a Yum Update on my Amazon Linux 2 instance (a T2.Medium) and after the update only 2 IP addresses per interface were working. Before the update I had 6 IPs per interface.  It looks like either the kernel update or the ec2-net-utils is the culprit.

I have tried ec2ifscan and several reboots, as well as dropping the IP and re-attaching it on the AWS control panel.

I can't see the IPs at all from within the instance, and I can't see anything out of place on the AWS side.

Here is list of what was updated.

Any suggestions for what happened and how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
===============================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                 Arch                          Version                                        Repository                          Size
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 ec2-net-utils                                           noarch                        1.5-2.amzn2                                    amzn2-core                          17 k
     replacing  ec2-net-utils.noarch 1.4-43.amzn2
 kernel                                                  x86_64                        4.14.231-173.360.amzn2                         amzn2-core                          21 M
Updating:
 ec2-instance-connect                                    noarch                        1.1-14.amzn2                                   amzn2-core                          23 k
 glibc                                                   x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         3.3 M
 glibc-all-langpacks                                     x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         7.0 M
 glibc-common                                            x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         770 k
 glibc-devel                                             x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         991 k
 glibc-headers                                           x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         511 k
 glibc-locale-source                                     x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         3.2 M
 glibc-minimal-langpack                                  x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                          29 k
 irqbalance                                              x86_64                        2:1.7.0-4.amzn2.0.1                            amzn2-core                          51 k
 java-11-amazon-corretto-headless                        x86_64                        1:11.0.11+9-1.amzn2                            amzn2-core                         164 M
 kernel-headers                                          x86_64                        4.14.231-173.360.amzn2                         amzn2-core                         1.1 M
 kernel-tools                                            x86_64                        4.14.231-173.360.amzn2                         amzn2-core                         142 k
 libcrypt                                                x86_64                        2.26-44.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                          49 k
 nettle                                                  x86_64                        2.7.1-9.amzn2                                  amzn2-core                         327 k
 openssh                                                 x86_64                        7.4p1-21.amzn2.0.3                             amzn2-core                         507 k
 openssh-clients                                         x86_64                        7.4p1-21.amzn2.0.3                             amzn2-core                         650 k
 openssh-server                                          x86_64                        7.4p1-21.amzn2.0.3                             amzn2-core                         456 k
Removing:
 kernel                                                  x86_64                        4.14.219-161.340.amzn2                         @amzn2-core                        101 M

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================
Install   2 Packages
Upgrade  17 Packages
Remove    1 Package
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Support has helped with this:

It turns out the new version ec2-net-utils messes with the network interfaces for its own purposes.

The work around is to:

```
yum downgrade ec2-net-utils 
reboot
```